# How to elevate Workflow permission?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

We have defined a SharePoint designer workflow in this case the workflow has full permission for CRUD operation on list called Employee. But the requirement is in conditional cases the same workflow should also add/edit/update item on the manager list, but to access manager list, elevating permissions needs to be elevated. Let us assume that an employee has logged in and he has started the workflow. 
How to get elevated permissions in this case?

Comment: Please Check [The workflow was suspended with unauthorized HTTP / elevate workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a step for this purpose. In SharePoint 2010 it called Impersonation step, in SharePoint 2013, it is called an App Step.

Whenever a workflow is fired, it is run as the user who initiated the workflow, whenever it hits the app/impersonation step, anything inside the step is run as either the workflow account (2013), or the author of the workflow (2010). Just make sure that that user has the correct permission on the "Manager" list.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

Comment: But in this case user doesn't have write permission on the manager list as he is a simple user. your answer is not correct.